# Kedro 0.17 Override global.yml with extra params

Tags: kedro

Im currently not able to update the globals.yml file with extra params passed at run time as I previously did with Kedro 0.16.x. I run kedro through run.py.

```
    @hook_impl
    def register_config_loader(self, conf_paths: Iterable[str]) -> ConfigLoader:
        session = get_current_session()
        extra_params = session.store.get('extra_params')
        loader = TemplatedConfigLoader(
            conf_paths,
            globals_pattern="*globals.yml",
            globals_dict=extra_params,
        )
        return loader
```

Trying the above provides the following error:

```
RuntimeError: There is no active Kedro session.
     60     @hook_impl
     61     def register_config_loader(self, conf_paths: Iterable[str]) -> ConfigLoader:
---> 62         session = get_current_session()
     63         extra_params = session.store.get('extra_params')
     64         loader = TemplatedConfigLoader(
```

My pipelines work without adding this but I of course cant override the globals.yml at run time (which is essential).

Comment: This will be fixed in 0.17.1. It's the same motivation behind this github issue as well: https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/issues/666